# Parse Hosting & JSSDK Query

Tags: parse-platform

I have setup PARSE hosting and I am trying to test retrieving an object from a Class in my Parse data however when I try to deploy I get the following error:

```
Update failed with Could not load triggers.  The error was Uncaught You must specify a key using Parse.initialize.
```

I set up my dynamic site based on the instructions in the Parse docs.

My code

```
var puppyClass = Parse.Object.extend('PCClass');
var query = new Parse.Query(puppyClass);

var puppies = [];
query.get("7S3NKS1oim", {
  success: function(puppy) {
    // The object was retrieved successfully.
    puppies.push(puppy);
  },
  error: function(object, error) {
    // The object was not retrieved successfully.
    // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the error message, you must have a call to `Parse.initialize("ApplicationIdHere", "JavaScriptKeyHere")`, replacing those values with your App ID and JavaScript Key. This should be called once on page-load.

Comment: Thanks for this my confusion was that I had thought by using PARSE hosting that the SDK would be initialised already. Where would I need to place this?

Comment: Thanks for the answer I realised that I was correct in my assumption but I was calling the wrong function

Comment: Where we need to add this Parse.initialize("ApplicationIdHere", "JavaScriptKeyHere") in the file ??

Comment: @ManoharSingh You would normally put it in your document-load handler, but you can just make it the first line of your JavaScript if you're not using jQuery or anything else that makes it easier to have a document-load handler.